# Why are browsers inserting a `\9` into this style attribute

Tags: javascript, css, browser

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.style.cssText = "background-image: url('http://imgs.com/mouse.png   ')";
div.style.cssText
//=> "background-image: url("http://imgs.com/mouse.png\9 ");"
```

The above code, with that being a tab after the `.png` suffix, when run in either Chrome or Firefox console will output the shown line with with `\9` appended to the URL. Why is that?

I've read that `\9` is some sort of a hack for targeting only specific versions of IE, but why would Chrome and Firefox be automatically inserting that?

PS: For additional browser fun, can you guess what happens if that URL is relative and you want to resolve it with the classic `<a>` href trick? Here's what would happen on the fictional `http://imgs.com` domain:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
// Actually parsed from the above response, not assigned manually
a.href = "/mouse.png\\9 ";
a.href
//=> "http://imgs.com/mouse.png/9"   (in Chrome)
//=> "http://imgs.com/mouse.png%5C9" (in Firefox)
```

So while the URL with the `\9` suffix would still actually work, the resolved URLs will now point to incorrect locations.

Comment: The tab character is also "CTRL-I".  The letter "I" is the ninth letter of the alphabet. `\9` is a CSS character escape.

Comment: If the console is doing it but the page itself always resolves it correctly, it's probably a bug in the console. My question is why is there whitespace in your css-string? Side note, the `\9` IE hack is placed at the end of the property (before the `;`), not in the middle of a string, and is either `\9` for 8-11 or ` \9` (that's an nbsp not an sp, do not copy paste) for I believe 5.5-8.

Comment: @Pointy That's... interesting. I mean, it's actually `\9` because TAB is ASCII (and by extension, UTF) `0x09`, and if it's `^i` it'd be because you use tabs for `i`ndenting... But that's a cool story none the less

Comment: @abluejelly, I used the console as an example, but the exact same thing happens even if run as plain code on the page. I actually found this while writing a test involving something similar.

Comment: @Pointy, @abluejelly, would either of you mind formulating this into a proper answer, please? With an explanation of why the codepoint value of 9 matters here and gets inserted as `\9`. I.e. why does it get escaped.

Comment: @abluejelly note that in a Linux terminal window, and certainly on a real ASCII terminal (if you can find one), CTRL-I works exactly like the tab key on your keyboard.

Comment: @Pointy I think what you meant to say was that `^h` is backspace because `0x08` is Backspace in ASCII/UTF. I wasn't contesting `^i` being a tab. Honestly not sure whether the chicken or the egg came first now.

Comment: @abluejelly no I meant `^I` - try it!

Comment: @Pointy Yes, `^i`. It works on even windows' cmd. However, I never said it didn't, I was contesting the _reason_ it was `^i`- hence why I just now pointed out backspace follows the same logic- h is the 8th letter, BKSP the character with code `0x08`.

Comment: @abluejelly It's definitely the alphabet: `^G` was the BELL character, `^C` is ETX (end of text), `^J` is line feed, etc. Old ASCII terminals were wired to produce those characters via the CTRL key.

Comment: @Pointy Yeah seeing that now. I'm used to thinking in more modern keyboard controls- like `ctrl+v` for paste, not `shift+insert`. Learn somethin' new most days, haha. Side note: hitting `^g` on the windows cmd, and hearing it beep at me made me giggle.

Answer (score 1):

When the console has to print out source code, it tries to do so in a way that's unambiguous. A tab character is not obviously a tab, and there are many other special characters with that same problem. Therefore, non-printable or non-obvious characters are rendered using an appropriate escape sequence, where "appropriate" means "appropriate to the language context".

CSS escapes look like `\nnnnnn` where the `n`s are hex digits. There can be from one to six such digits. The escape `\9` is the escape for the tab character.

Note that in actual CSS source text, you too can use actual tab characters and the notation `\9` interchangeably and get precisely the same results, because the CSS parser interprets `\9` as a single tab character, just like an actual tab character.

The described behavior of the console is not in any standard (because the developer tools themselves are not standardized), but it's the sort of thing that any designer of such tools is very likely to do.

Comment: About the only thing I'd add is that the source for the code points the hex digits correspond to is either UTF or the code page the CSS file is in. Not quite sure which, but since generally the CSS file is in UTF-8, they'd be equivalent most of the time, hence my uncertainty without looking at a spec.

Comment: I think this misses the point by focusing on the console. See and run this for example: https://plnkr.co/edit/rbmKYgnU4p3aixgNZaMu